# Keep REGEX delimiter with greedy token

Tags: java, regex, delimiter, scientific-notation

Good day,

I'm writing a equation evaluator in Java and are using REGEX to identify values, including scientific notation, which I found in one of the feeds (and adopted slightly), which looks as follows:

`[\d.]+(?:E-?\d+)?`

The problem I'm experiencing is that I want to keep the delimited value. How can I do that? I played around with it on regex101.com, however, when I use look ahead and look behind, it complains about the greedy tokens.

I have found several other REGEX on StackOverflow but couldn't find one that keeps the delimiters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by `The problem I'm experiencing is that I want to keep the delimited value.` ? Can you add some examples to the question?

Comment: @Thefourthbird, for example, if I say:
```String eqn = "cos(2123.324E3)*ln(e^x)+123.345E-6*sin(sin(sin(x)))";
String[] eqnSplit = eqn.split("([\\d.]+(?:E-?\\d+)?)");```
I get the following results: [cos(, )*ln(e^x)+, *sin(sin(sin(x)))]
So the values, which in this instance are the delimiter (if my terminology is correct), is removed. However, I still want the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using split, you could use an alternation to either get the match, of match all chars that are not directly followed by the first pattern.

```
[\d.]+(?:E-?\d+)?|(?:(?![\d.]+(?:E-?\d+)?).)+
```

The pattern matches:

- `[\d.]+(?:E-?\d+)?` Your pattern for the scientific notation
- `|` Or
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?![\d.]+(?:E-?\d+)?).` Negative lookahead, match a single char when the scientific notation is not directly to the right
- `)+` Close non capture group, and repeat 1+ times to match at least a single char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/duLJC4/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/ybTl9E)

For example

```
String regex = "[\\d.]+(?:E-?\\d+)?|(?:(?![\\d.]+(?:E-?\\d+)?).)+";
String string = "cos(2123.324E3)*ln(e^x)+123.345E-6*sin(sin(sin(x)))";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output

```
cos(
2123.324E3
)*ln(e^x)+
123.345E-6
*sin(sin(sin(x)))
```

Comment: I did 1'000 iterations using both the split and the matcher methods and the matcher method preformed faster

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the fastest thing in the world but you **could** do **something** like this:

```
/**
 * Holds onto and supplies the supplied split delimiter(s) to the split
 * array elements.<br><br>
 * <p>
 * This method creates a Regular Expression (RegEx) that is to be placed
 * within a String.split() method to acquire the desired array
 * content.<br><br>
 *
 * @param inputString       (String) The string to split.<br>
 *
 * @param delimiterPosition (Integer) A integer value of either 0, 1, or 2.
 *                          The specific value determines how the detected
 *                          delimiter types are placed within the array:<pre>
 *
 *      0       Delimiter as separate element:
 *              a;b;c;d = [a, ;, b, ;, c, ;, d]
 *              Core regex is: .split("((?&lt;=;)|(?=;))")
 *              Lookahead and Lookbehind used.
 *
 *      1       Delimiter at end of each element except last:
 *              a;b;c;d = [a;, b;, c;, d]
 *              Core regex is: .split("(?&lt;=;)")
 *              Lookahead used only.
 *
 *      2       Delimiter at beginning of each element except first:
 *              a;b;c;d = [a, ;b, ;c, ;d]
 *              Core regex is: .split("(?=;)")
 *              Lookbehind used only.</pre><br>
 *
 * If nothing is supplied then each character of the supplied input string
 * is split into the sting array.<br><br>
 *
 * If any supplied delimiters or delimiter characters happen to be RegEx
 * Meta Characters such as: ( ) [ ] { { \ ^ $ | ? * + . &lt; &gt; - = ! for
 * example then those delimiters must be Escaped with a Double Backslash
 * (ie: "\\+" ) when supplied otherwise an exception will occur.<br>
 *
 * @param delimiters        (1D String Array or one to multiple comma
 *                          delimited String Entries) Any number of string
 *                          delimiters can be supplied as long as they are
 *                          separated with a comma (,).<br>
 *
 * @return (String) The Regular Expression (RegEx) to be used within a
 *         String.split() method.
 */
public static String[] SplitAndKeepDelimiters(String inputString, int delimiterPosition, String... delimiters) {
    if (delimiters.length < 1) {
        return inputString.split("");
    }

    // build regex...
    String regEx = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < delimiters.length; i++) {
        switch (delimiterPosition) {
            case 0:
                regEx += regEx.isEmpty() ? "((?<=" + delimiters[i] + ")|(?=" + delimiters[i] + "))"
                        : "|((?<=" + delimiters[i] + ")|(?=" + delimiters[i] + "))";
                break;
            case 1:
                regEx += regEx.isEmpty() ? "(?<=" + delimiters[i] + ")"
                        : "|(?<=" + delimiters[i] + ")";
                break;
            case 2:
                regEx += regEx.isEmpty() ? "(?=" + delimiters[i] + ")"
                        : "|(?=" + delimiters[i] + ")";
                break;
        }
    }
    return inputString.split(regEx);
}
```

The above method will allow you to split on multiple delimiters.